# Powershell copy files to different locations based on file names from destination folder

Tags: file, powershell, copy

I would like to copy files from source folder to different locations that already exists. Source folder looks like this:

```
y:\source\00001_w01.jpg
y:\source\00001_w02.jpg
y:\source\00002_w01.jpg
y:\source\00003_w01.jpg
```

Destination folder structure look like this:

```
y:\destination\120\04397\00001-00001-new_doc.jpg
y:\destination\120\04397\00001-00002-new_doc.jpg
y:\destination\120\04397\00002-00001-00001.jpg
y:\destination\120\04397\00002-00002-00001.jpg
```

I need to copy files from source folder (00001_w01.jpg, 00001_w02.jpg) to destinaton folder after first file which last part in it's name matches first part in source file name.

After copy destination folder structure will look like this:

```
y:\destination\120\04397\00001-00001-new_doc.jpg
y:\destination\120\04397\00001-00002-new_doc.jpg
y:\destination\120\04397\00002-00001-00001.jpg
y:\destination\120\04397\00002-00001-00001-00001_w01.jpg
y:\destination\120\04397\00002-00001-00001-00001_w02.jpg
y:\destination\120\04397\00002-00002-00001.jpg
```

Where

```
y:\destination\120\04397\00002-00001-00001-00001_w01.jpg = y:\source\00001_w01.jpg
y:\destination\120\04397\00002-00001-00001-00001_w02.jpg = y:\source\00001_w02.jpg
```

My biggest problem is how to match those files. Any ideas?

Comment: I need to copy files from source folder (00001_w01.jpg, 00001_w02.jpg) to destinaton folder after first file which last part in it's name matches first part in source file name. -- can you show exactly what you are matching. you can then use $sourcefile.Trimstart() and $destfile.Trimend() - show where the names intersect.

Comment: First 5 digits from source file (00001 from 00001_w01.jpg) must match last 5 digits from destination file (00001 from 00002-00001-00001.jpg ). Destination file name can be divided to three sections - only last section with digits must match.

Comment: Your description is still ambiguous. How do you identify the destination folder? According to your rule the last example also matches `00002-00002-00001.jpg` it's also unclear if it's always the third group or the last before the extension to match.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Destination folder is indentified by file names in it. That's true that my rule also matches 00002-00002-00001.jpg. To clarify the rule only first file from the destination files with the correct number is accepted (when files are sorted of course). it is always third group.